# How can I use iptables to forward all traffic through an interface based in gid?

Tags: networking, debian, vpn, openvpn, iptables

I'm on Debian 12 bookworm

I'm trying to forward all traffic from (and to) users in the group `watchers` through interface tun9 and prevent them from using enp2s0.

I've set up a tunnel using openvpn with the settings from protonvpn using a free-tier (one IP address - which is all I need).

But I'm having problems with it...

I set up a service at `/etc/systemd/system/proton.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=ProtonVPN for Watchers
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/protonvpn/<file-location>.ovpn
ExecStartPost=/etc/openvpn/protonvpn/routing.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here's the contents of `/etc/openvpn/protonvpn/routing.sh` referenced in the service file above.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Flush existing rules
iptables -F

NET=192.168.0.0/24
GROUP=watchers
IFACE_INTERNAL=enp2s0
IFACE_VPN=tun9
ALLOW_PORT_FROM_LOCAL=2000

iptables -A OUTPUT -d $NET -p tcp --sport $ALLOW_PORT_FROM_LOCAL -m owner --gid-owner $GROUP -o $IFACE_VPN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $NET -p udp --sport $ALLOW_PORT_FROM_LOCAL -m owner --gid-owner $GROUP -o $IFACE_VPN -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner $GROUP -o $IFACE_VPN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner $GROUP -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner ! --uid-owner $GROUP -m owner --gid-owner $GROUP -j REJECT

iptables -A INPUT -i $IFACE_VPN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $IFACE_INTERNAL -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner /! --gid-owner $GROUP -o $IFACE_INTERNAL -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD
```

And here's (some of) the contents of the `.ovpn`

```
client
dev tun9
proto tcp

remote <ip address removed> 8443
remote <ip address removed> 7770
remote <ip address removed> 

remote-random
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

cipher AES-256-GCM

setenv CLIENT_CERT 0
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix 0
persist-key
persist-tun

reneg-sec 0

remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/protonvpn/creds.txt

script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf

and all my certs below....
```

I've tried a number of iptables rules but none of them seem to work.

I bring the service up and it appears to run perfectly.

When I run `curl --interface tun9 icanhazip.com`, I get the correct ip address for the VPN.
Also, when I run `sudo -u watchers curl icanhazip.com` I also get the correct ip for the VPN.

However, when I run `curl icanhazip.com` from a user that is not in the watchers group (any other user), I get the VPN ip as well.

The only way I can get the non-VPN ip is if I force it in curl (`curl --interface enp2s0 icanhazip.com`).

Any help would be appreciated.